# Translate Excel Solver to solve Non Linear Programming in Python

Tags: python, optimization, solver, nonlinear-optimization

I need to solve a Non-Linear Programming equation using the data shown on the spreadsheet. It is reproducible using Excel Solver (or Google Sheet Solver). I just do not know how to translate the equation to solver, pulp or sympy.

Below is the screenshot along with the solution on Google Sheet:

[image]

On the Solver editor, I put cell P15 as input for "Set Objective" whereby it is a formula (P15-$I15), I choose the "Max" option and put cell J15 as input for "By Changing".

How can translate this to Python?

Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this question using Scipy.minimize library.